# How to view load test reports by individual request in Visual Studio Team edition

Tags: visual-studio, testing, load-testing

When performance testing a web site using the Load Web Test of Visual Studio one gets a summary of the results. Useful measures are shown, like the average response time, maximum response time etc.

One thing that intrigues me is being able to drill down to specific requests if needed, answering questions like what was the single request taking the most time. One can set the Timing Details Storage property of the Run Settings to "All Individual Details", but that only seems to give aggregation per URI, ignoring changes to the query parameters. In my scenario, http://somewebsite/dosomething.ashx?cmd=find is very different from http://somewebsite/dosomething.ashx?cmd=nothing . How do I generate a report which distinguish those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Loadtests in VSTS 2008 doesn't allow you to capture request details at a granular level. I've read VSTS 2010(still in beta) has a feature which will allow you to do something similar.
http://blogs.msdn.com/billbar/archive/2009/06/09/vsts-2010-load-test-feature-saving-test-logs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try to check the visual studio reporting tool at http://www.qualiwebsolutions.com/

Answer (score 0):

(this feature was new in VS 2008 or 2010, not sure which):  select the query string parameter on your request, and in the Properties pane there is a property "Show Separate Request Results".  Set this to True, and then Visual Studio will record separate page results for all variations of that query string parameter.